# Transition Kernel, is there a meaning to $P(B,A)$ where $A$ and $B$ are set?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> If one defines a transition kernel (for markov chains) as:
>
> $$P(x_n, A) := \mathbb P( x_{n+1} \in A \mid x_n ), \qquad A \in \mathcal
>  B(\mathbb R) $$

then, first, do you think it is meaningful to write down $ P(B, A)$, where by that I mean:

$$P(B, A) =  \mathbb P( x_{n+1} \in A \mid x_n \in B ) $$

**and then, would it be true to write:**

$$ P(B, A) = \mathbb P( x_{n+1} \in A \mid x_n \in B ) = \int  P(y, A) d \mathbb 
P(y) $$
where the last integral is taken over the set of possible $x_n$.

> The thing is, I struggle to prove (which is the main object of the
>   question):
>
> $$ \mathbb P(x_n \in B \mid x_0 ) \mathbb P( x_{n+1} \in A \mid x_n
>  \in B) = P^n(x_0,B) P(B,A) =  \int_B P(y,A) P^n(x_0,dy)  \quad \qquad
>  (*) $$

and using the bold equation (which maybe is false), in order to get :

$$ P^n(x_0,B) P(B,A) = \int P^n(x_0,dy) P(y, A)  $$

this may comes down to the fact that I haven't fully understand kernels yet.

Comment: The problem is this: you say "an integral taken over the set of possible $x_n$", but with respect to what measure?  You write $dP(y)$ but what's $P$?  There's no measure that's intrinsically natural here, which is why this notation doesn't really make sense.

Comment: If you have an overall probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on your sample space, which corresponds roughly to making a choice of what the initial distribution of the chain should be, then you have a measure, but it's not really intrinsic since it depends on more than just the transition function of the chain, so it's misleading to write it as though it only involves $P$.

Comment: @NateEldredge  you're totally write, i wanted to write $d \mathbb P$ not $d P$. Then how would you prove $(*)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, using the law of total probability was enough in order to prove what I wanted. By that I mean :

$$ \mathbb P(x_n \in B \mid x_0 ) \mathbb P( x_{n+1} \in A \mid x_n
\in B)  =
\mathbb P(x_{n+1} \in A \mid x_0 ) $$

$$
\mathbb P(x_{n+1} \in A \mid x_0 ) =  
\int P(y,A) P^n(x_0,dy)
$$

there is no need for the set $B$. It makes things unnecessarly overly complicated.